# Projecting KITTI velodyne to image produces a narrow strip

Tags: python, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, projection

I am trying to project the [KITTI velodyne](http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/eval_object.php?obj_benchmark=3d) onto the left camera images. I followed the README in the KITTI devkit, but the result is off -- the points are projected as a narrow band on the top of the image. The band looks like it has some distribution, so I am suspecting I am doing something wrong with the calibration matrices. Or maybe in the `PIL.ImageDraw.point`?

The projection equation that I am using is per the KITTI devkit documentation:

- `x = P2 * R0_rect * Tr_velo_to_cam * y`, where

  - `y` is a `4xN` matrix with `N` points in `XYZL` format (`L` is the luminescence),
  - `Tr_velo_to_cam` is the `3x4` velodyne to camera transformation matrix
  - `R0_rect` is the `3x3` extrinsic camera rotation matrix
  - `P2` is the `3x3` intrinsic camera projection matrix

Below is the code, STDIO of it, and the produced image.

`test.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

DATASET_PATH = "<DATASET PATH HERE>"

vld_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, "velodyne/{:06d}.bin")
img_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, "image_2/{:06d}.png")
clb_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, "calib/{:06d}.txt")

frame_num = 58

# Load files
img = Image.open(img_path.format(frame_num))
clb = {}
with open(clb_path.format(frame_num), 'r') as clb_f:
  for line in clb_f:
    calib_line = line.split(':')
    if len(calib_line) < 2:
      continue
    key = calib_line[0]
    value = np.array(list(map(float, calib_line[1].split())))
    value = value.reshape((3, -1))
    clb[key] = value
vld = np.fromfile(vld_path.format(frame_num), dtype=np.float32)
vld = vld.reshape((-1, 4)).T

print("img.shape:", np.shape(img))
print("P2.shape:", clb['P2'].shape)
print("R0_rect.shape:", clb['R0_rect'].shape)
print("Tr_velo_to_cam.shape:", clb['Tr_velo_to_cam'].shape)
print("vld.shape:", vld.shape)

# Reshape calibration files
P2 = clb['P2']
R0 = np.eye(4)
R0[:-1, :-1] = clb['R0_rect']
Tr = np.eye(4)
Tr[:-1, :] = clb['Tr_velo_to_cam']

# Prepare 3d points
pts3d = vld[:, vld[-1, :] > 0].copy()
pts3d[-1, :] = 1

# Project 3d points
pts3d_cam = R0 @ Tr @ pts3d
mask = pts3d_cam[2, :] >= 0  # Z >= 0
pts2d_cam = P2 @ pts3d_cam[:, mask]
pts2d = (pts2d_cam / pts2d_cam[2, :])[:-1, :]

print("pts2d.shape:", pts2d.shape)

# Draw the points
img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img_draw.point(pts2d, fill=(255, 0, 0))
img.show()
```

STDOUT:

```
$> python ./test.py 
img.shape: (370, 1224, 3)
P2.shape: (3, 4)
R0_rect.shape: (3, 3)
Tr_velo_to_cam.shape: (3, 4)
vld.shape: (4, 115052)
pts2d.shape: (2, 53119)
```

Produced image:

[image: Projection fail]

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem: Notice that the dimensions of the `pts2d` are `(2, N)`, which means it has N points in total. However, the `ImageDraw` routine expects it to be either `Nx2` or `1x2N` row vector with alternating `x` and `y` values. Although I couldn't get the `point` routine to work with the `Nx2` input, I put it in the for loop (after transposing the points), and it worked.

```
# ...
pts2d = (pts2d_cam / pts2d_cam[2, :])[:-1, :].T

print("pts2d.shape:", pts2d.shape)

# Draw the points
img_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
for point in pts2d:
  img_draw.point(point, fill=(255, 0, 0))
# ...
```

[image: Projection successful]